# Can I run grep against a zOS dataset via Unix system services?

Tags: grep, zos

I have a search I'd like to run against a zOS dataset, and I know how to form the grep command.  I have access to the machine via Unix system services, how to I address a dataset from that environment?

Comment: +1  I think it is the first z/OS question around here :)

Comment: @kubanczyk I've got plenty more if you want them ...

Comment: Absolutely - I don't think we have many z/OS folks but good questions would go a long way to attracting them :)

Comment: some doubts are cleared after reading this question. thanks

Answer (score 5):

No need to cp first. You can cat, tail, grep etc. The thing to remember is the special quoting and that the DSN is preceded by two slashes:

cat "//'s052WX.EO.REXX(MYREXXSOURCE)'" | grep parse

If you look in the UNIX command reference manual under the cp command there’s more info.

Answer (score 3):

How big a data set are we talking about?
The Unix system services `cp` command can take data sets as a source, and a Unix file (or directory) as a target, so conceivably if the data set is small enough you can copy it into files and `grep` away to your heart's content.

As an alternative, if you can open your data set in `ISPF` on the z/OS machine you may want to consider using [FINDRX](http://www.sillysot.com/ftp/findrx.txt) (which gives ISPF basic regex capability) -- I've never used it myself though so I can't vouch for it working or not.

Comment: The data sets aren't that big (COBOL source), but there are 200+ of them ...

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can use `dgrep` command

As the manual says:

> "Search for a pattern across all datasets (partitioned and sequential) matching one or more dataset patterns"

The syntax:

```
dgrep [-hinvd] [-C<num>] <pattern> [<dataset-pattern>]+
     -h: syntax
     -i: ignore case
     -n: display line numbers
     -v: print names of datasets being searched
     -d: print debug messages
     -C: display <num> lines of context around a match
```

For example:

```
$ dgrep DSALET36 IBMUSER.*.ISPPROF

IBMUSER.SYSTEM.ISPF.ISPPROF                 ISRLLIST   34
```

More applications and examples:
[here](https://makingdeveloperslivesbetter.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/working-with-mvs-datasets-from-uss/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there are two options:

1. Copy files to uss-filesystem and `grep` there as mentioned above;
   works for me.
2. Create an external link
   (`~ /usr/sbin/mount -f host.quali.pda -O 'SYNC(120)' mountpoint`)
   and `grep` via that link; currently not
   working for me because of rights-restrictions.

The `cat`-suggestion works well for a single file, but not for all pds-members (at least i was not able to make it work).

Answer (score 0):

- z/OS supports UNIX ([Single UNIX Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification)) APIs and applications through [USS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_Services) (**U**NIX **S**ystem **S**ervices).
- The Open Group certifies z/OS as a compliant UNIX operating system – with UNIX/Linux-style hierarchical HFS and zFS file systems.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread after banging my head against the wall for about an hour.
My expereince - as very much a newbie on Z/OS, MVS, etc - is that grep against a PD (or is it a PDS, or a DSN, who knows!) is that this cannot be done directly

So, let's say I have text in a location like this:  MYUSERID.SOME.DATA(DATA1)
(let me just interject, I have no idea how to refer to such a data "thing", I think it's a "PD")

Now, if I try to grep against the PD, using what seems like reasonable syntax:

```
===>grep FindMe "//'MYUSERID.SOME.DATA(DATA1)'"

$ grep: FSUM6261 read error on file "//'MYUSERID.SOME.DATA(DATA1)'": EDC511
3I Bad file descriptor.
```

Some other UNIX utility functions do work, for example:

```
===>cat "//'MYUSERID.SOME.DATA(DATA1)'"
```

and

```
===>cp "//'MYUSERID.SOME.DATA(DATA1)'" ./data.data
```

Others, rather unhelpfully, do not:

```
==>ls "//'MYUSERID.SOME.DATA(DATA1)'"
ls: FSUM6785 File or directory "//'MYUSERID.SOME.DATA(DATA1)'" is not found
```

AND - don't forget, the pipe is your friend, except it may not be the "|" character.
It might very be the "!" (exclamation point) character.

This is basically an exercise in "try it out" the way you would in a real OS/SHELL combination, linux/BASH for example, and when that doesn't work, come up with a workaround for this idiotic, archaic System.

So my solution to your exact question is:

```
===> cat "//'MYUSERID.SOME.DATA(DATA1)'" ! grep FindMe
```